# How to extend Oracle Users Tablespace?

Tags: database, oracle11g, tablespace

Does anyone know, I want to extend my current user table space. So do I need to shutdown the instance or can change unlimited directly without shutting down the instance? Does it has relationship?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A tablespace is usually made of datafiles.

So you can add a new datafile, or change the existing datafile autoextend.

See Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3002.htm)